# Refresh function when navigated to a page again in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my wpf app I have two pages, `page1` and `page2`.

when the user go from `page1` to `page2` in the first time it automatically creates a new `page2`.

in `page1` it looks something like:

```
public static int someVar;
public Page1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
.
.
.
// the user gives some value to "someVar"
void Next_btn(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
        this.NavigationService.GoForward();
     else
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
}
```

in `page2` it looks like:

```
public Page2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   if(Page1.someVar==3)
      DoSomething();
}
.
.
.
void Back_btn(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

My problem is this:

let's say that the user done the following:

the user have been in `page1` and puts `someVar=2` and then goes to `page2`. therefore the function `DoSomething()` wont be called.
after that he went back to page1 and changed `someVar=3` and then navigated again to page2 still the function `DoSomething()` wont be called(But I need that it will be called it this scenario), because it's not a **new** `page2`.

how to solve the following scenario without navigate to a new `page2` every time?

Comment: how to notify that the user navigated from page1 to page2?

Comment: You could handle the Navigated or LoadCompleted event of the NavigationService.

Comment: plz show me a code example as answer

Comment: The parent should be responsible for navigation and for creating new children. The parent should do this, not the children. Classes should have no knowledge of their siblings, and should have limited knowledge of their parents, if any. Give each child a Next event and a Previous event. The parent would then handle those events and take care of the navigation in its handlers. The parent can easily have references to all the children because it created them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the constructor will only be executed once for each instance of Page2.

But you could handle the `Navigated` event for the `NavigationService` in `Page1` and call the `DoSomething()` method of `Page2` in the event handler. Something like this:

```
void Next_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigated += NavigationService_Navigated;

    if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
        this.NavigationService.GoForward();
    else
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
}

private void NavigationService_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var page2 = NavigationService.Content as Page2;
    if (page2 != null && someVar == 3)
        page2.DoSomething();

    this.NavigationService.Navigated -= NavigationService_Navigated;
}
```

Comment: gives null exeption on this like `var page2 = NavigationService.Content as Page2` do you know why?

Comment: What is null? The NavigationService? Then your current code cannot work either.

Comment: NavigationService.Content threw null exeption

Comment: maybe because there isn't instance of page2 yet?

Comment: gives null exeption on this line `var page2 = NavigationService.Content as Page2`

Comment: I succeeded, you gave me the idea for it, but there are some changes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `@8mm` for his guidance, the following code worked for me:

```
Page2 p2=new Page2();
void Next_btn(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
        {
           p2.DoSomething();
            this.NavigationService.GoForward();
        } else
            NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
    }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't mention the fact that you made DoSomething() static, which as you discovered was a bad idea. I can infer that by looking at the answer, but that won't be obvious to anybody who's inexperienced enough to be having trouble with a similar issue. How'd your next question work out? Any progress on disabling that textbox in a static method that shouldn't be static? Is that code working?

Comment: It can be easily chaneg to non static

Comment: OK, make it non-static. How do you call it then?

Comment: `Page2 p2=new Page2(); `
`p2.DoSomething();`

Comment: So you're making everything else static, just so you can call a non-static method on the wrong instance.

Comment: Right, that's what I just told you: It's a non-static method. You're calling it on a temp instance of Page2 that you immediately throw away, right? So if it's doing anything to the *other* instance of Page2, you must have a lot of other stuff that's static.

Comment: If `p2` is now a private non-static field and you're only creating it once, that's the answer I gave you, and while not ideal, it's infinitely better than making things static. Since you're initializing the field now, I presume your null reference exception was because you were messing with `_page2` somewhere else before creating it.

Comment: Now I understand your sudden enlightenment: You got this code from mm8 in another question.

Comment: mm8's answer gives exeption also. my code isn't, I don't understand your downvote

Comment: What exception? What line? What did you do to fix it?

Comment: I wrote the line ander mm8's answer. what I did? the code says all

Comment: No, it isn't see date and time when I post mine and when he post his answer, my answer came earlier

Comment: Well, what do you know. You got the answer from me after all.